New column based on relationship between 2 other columns
I have 2 tables A and B with indirect relations between them (meaning that they are not directly connected, but they are both connected to a table C). Table A has a many to one relation to table C, and table B has a one to many relation to table C.
In table A I have a column with the Owner Region (Asia, Europe, North America...) and in table B I have a column with Execution Region (Asia, Europe, North America...).
I would like to create a visual table where I have on the first column the Owner Region column and on the second column I would like to make a column (named Home_Away) that checks the Execution Region column and based on the Owner Region column it either says "Home" or "Away". To give an example:
If Owner Region is Asia and Execution Region is Asia then Home, if Owner Region is Asia and Execution Region is Europe then Away.
So in the end I would like the table to look like:



Owner Region
Home_Away




Asia
Home


Asia
Away


Europe
Home


Europe
Away


North Am.
Home


North Am.
Away



Right now I have this:
IF(LOOKUPVALUE('A'[Owner Region], 'A'[Sales Person ID], MAX('B'[Sales Person ID])) = MAX('B'[Execution Region]), "Home", "Away" )
However, this requires me to add the Execution Region column in the visual table (which I do not want, I would like to just have the Home_Away column). If I remove it the Max function aggregates in a way that doesn't align with what I need (i.e. it chooses either Home or Away based on the data in the tables and doesn't display both in the visual table). So the visual table looks like this:



Owner Region
Home_Away




Asia
Home


Europe
Home


North Am.
Away



Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated! Thanks

could you pls provide some sample data of three tables and the expected output based on the sample data you provided?

I'm not sure if I can, as it contains customer information from the company I work at. Which part is unclear? Maybe I can try and explain it better. Sorry for not making it easy, and thank you for taking the time to look into it.

you can create some dummy data.otherwise, it's very hard to understand the data model and provide the solution
